# How to access theme colors for user control custom rendering with theming via MahApps.Metro or MUI

Tags: wpf, themes, wpf-controls, mahapps.metro

I have a number of UserControls that ultimately perform rendering via FrameworkElement::OnRender(). I draw custom thumb-bars, highlightable elements, buttons, and would like to make my controls responsive to the active theme. I use MahApps.Metro, and wonder how I can extra the current colours for certain features out of the active theme.

I don't use styles of any kind right now as I have just knocked together the controls using explicit brushes and pens, but I recognize the need to move in that direction.

How do I organize my pens and brushes to respond to the current theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mahapps metro source code for theme colors and brushes is available here:

https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Themes/Theme.Template.xaml

So the short answer is you should use DynamicResource notation for brushes and colors and try the keys there:

eg

```
<Rectangle  Fill={DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Button.Flat.Background}"
```

I would advise some experimentation to check brushes and colours are definitely set in themes you intend using and your ui works with them.

Comment: I was looking for that solution, thank you.  In my searches I did find how to do it in Code Behind, however, which you did not mention so if anyone is trying to find that answer...

``Brush background = (Brush)ThemeManager.Current.DetectTheme(Application.Current).Resources["MahApps.Brushes.Button.Flat.Background"];``